# Excel merge two sheets with One to many map

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two different sheets in Excel. I want to map value from a column in sheet 1 with every value in sheet 2 and that should repeat for every value in sheet 1.

```
Sheet 1 :
ID
1
2

Sheet 2 :
Dept
A
B
C

Expectation :
Dept  Id
A     1
B     1
C     1
A     2
B     2 
C     2
```

Please help, how can this be acheived with Excel.

Thanks

Comment: Try: `=SORT(DROP(REDUCE(0,A3:A4,LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,IFERROR(HSTACK(C3:C5,b),b)))),1),2)`